# Using Python to analyze large set of sensor-data

Tags: python, excel, pandas, sensors

I'm a researcher new to Python, and I have to analyze a large dataset that contains raw sensordata in an Excel format.

Each Excel-datafile is >100 MB's large for each study participant. The excelfile contains 5 sheets for the measurement of 5 different physiological parameters. Each sheet contains more than 1 million rows and two columns  (time, physiological parameter).

After 1 million rows of sensordata, the data automatically continues in the following columns (C and D) in the Excel file.

Every time I try to load the datafile in Python, it takes forever. I was wondering several things:

1) How do I tell Python to read data from a **specific** Excel sheet? Is it normal that this takes so long?

This is what I tried:

```
df = pd.read_excel("filepath", sheet_name="Sheetname")
print (df.head (5))
```

2) Is it feasible to do data munging for this large datafile in Python with Pandas? I tried this to speed up the process:

```
import xlrd
work_book = xlrd.open_workbook('filepath', on_demand=True)
work_book.release_resources()
```

3) Later on: I want to compare the physiological parameters of different study participants. As this is a time-series analysis between study participants, how could I get started doing this in Python?

I've learned the basics of Python in a few days, and I love it so far. I realize I have a long way to go.

Update: I think I just finished the time-series analysis (actually just the trend-analysis, using the Dickey-Fuller test and rolling mean visualisation techniques)! :D Thank you all so much for your help!!! The 'datetime' module in pandas was the hardest for me to get around, and my datetime column is still recognized as 'object'. Is this normal? Shouldn't it be datetime64?

Comment: To help you speed up the loading, we need to see how you are doing it now. Can you edit your question to include that part of your code?

Comment: I just added that, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, it doesn't sound like you will need to continually read in the data from a changing Excel sheet(s). I would recommend reading in the Excel sheets as you have done and storing them in serialized `pandas` dataframes using `to_pickle()`:

```
import pandas as pd

participants = ['P1','P2','P3']
physios = ['Ph1','Ph2','Ph3','Ph4','Ph5']

for p in participants:
    for ph in physios:
        df = pd.read_excel(p + r'.xlsx', sheet_name=ph)
        df.to_pickle(p + '_' + ph + r'.pkl')
```

You can now read these pickled dataframes much more efficiently since you don't have to incur all of the Excel overhead. A good discussion is available [here](https://tech.popdata.org/Fast-Excel-Slurping-With-Pandas-And-Pickle/).

Comment: Ah, that is so helpful! I will try that too, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

The dataset you are describing sounds like it's the sort of problem targeted by the `dask` project. It lets you use most of the standard `pandas` commands in parallel, out-of-memory.

The only problem is, dask doesn't have an excel reader from what I can tell. Since your question suggests the data don't fit in memory... you might want to manually convert the data to csv in excel, then you can simply:

```
# After pip install dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv("./relpath/to/csvs/*.csv")
# Do data munging here
df.compute()
```

If that doesn't work, maybe it would be better if you try to load the data into spark or a database and do the transforms there.

Re: your question about time-series, start by reading the docs on this subject [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html).

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your reply! :) I will try this and report back on how it turned out.

Comment: The question describes datasets that are only hundreds of megabytes, which can definitely fit in memory.

Comment: @Michael It only said greater than 100, and also mentioned having trouble loading into memory in a timely fashion, which is what gave me that impression. You're right, I was probably mistaken.

Comment: Each datafile contains 5 spreadsheets. Each spreadsheet contains 2 columns and 1 million rows. Loading time for printing just the first 5 rows of 1 spreadsheet with PyCharm is approximately 4 minutes. I have 8 GB RAM memory, intel core I5 processor. I hope it's not a memory problem..

Comment: Yes that sounds like it should be manageable. The `.head` method definitely should not take 4 minutes, my guess is that's actually from the `read_excel` command

Comment: Yes, I think that's correct! I split the file into 5 separate files and the reading time was much faster. Another update: I think I successfuly finished my time-series analysis. Thanks to all of you! :D

Comment: That's good @SamFloral! If one of the responses answered your question, remember to mark it as such!